# Flash Issue index.html

Tags: html, flash

I know very little about flash but my news works website it written in this but not working and I've been asked to have a look. The problem is the login page is corrupted and so will not allow you to go past it but thats where most of the website is (My plan is to create a HTML copy of the site) The only html page I see is index.html and when on the page and you click a link, the address bar along the top still remains at index.html, does anyone know how I can get into the flash site (I have this offline) so I can edit the login page and thus copy the code/information.

Thanks for you're time
Ross

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what's wrong without any code, would you care to share the source code with us?

Also, some interpunction would help. It's very hard to make up what you're trying to say here, because everying is one big sentence.

Comment: Here is the code for the page index.html, As you can see there is a link to an openject called....main_v8.swf, is this where the rest of the website is? I have links on index.html for: Home Page, What We Do, Login, Contact Us

Comment: <body> <div id="head">  <div class="aligncenter"><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/EN_US-H-GET-FLASH"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_adobe_flash_player.png" alt="" /></a></div> </div> <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" value="staff">staff</input> </div> <script type="text/javascript">
var fo = new FlashObject("main_v8.swf", "head", "100%", "100%", "8", "");
      fo.addParam("quality", "high");
      fo.addParam("allowFullScreen", "true");
      fo.write("head");
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Just to clarify, the above is the code for index.html which has links on it to toher pages namely, Home Page, What We Do, Login, Contact Us. The login page has become corrupted and does not allow you to login in, there is a page in the directory called, mylogin.aspx but I don't see a link for it on index.html

Comment: If this is the complete source code of the web page, then I'd say the site is made in Flash entirely, including the login area. The links are in Flash too (unless you left them out in your comment).I've already seen and answered your other question about getting the source code too, btw ;)